# transferring drupal site from localhost to live server

Tags: drupal-6

i have copied the drupal files to the live server using fzilla, now when i open the live site it says site offline,The mysql error was: Unknown MySQL server host 'dbramha' (1).,in settings.php i have given db_url as $db_url = 'mysql://dbramha/testing', testing is the database used locally, do i have to install drupal again in the server?

Answer (score 0):

The error is Drupal saying it can't see the database. Depending on your hosting arrangement for the live server this may or may not be on the same server as the Drupal installation.(It's most likely on another server though)

Have you uploaded the database? - Most commonly done by producing a SQL dump from the local development DB and importing it into the live one.

Just copying the Drupal files is only half of the story.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the db_url like this

```
 * Database URL format:
 *   $db_url = 'mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename';
 *   $db_url = 'mysqli://username:password@localhost/databasename';
 *   $db_url = 'pgsql://username:password@localhost/databasename';;
```

you have also to put your mysql in the live DB :)